# How to capitalize at the beginning of a sentence a word that has a fixed capitalization?

Tags: sentence-construction, capitalization

When asking a [question on another SE site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159292/is-there-a-time-limit-on-current-easyjets-rebooking-fees-0%E2%82%AC), it was brought to my attention that the airline company **easyJet** is spelled with a lowercase **e** and a capital **J** (I initially wrote *EasyJet*).

How should such a word be capitalized at the beginning of a sentence:

> EasyJet is an airline.

or

> easyJet is an airline.

Comment: The general question is answered below, but note that the official name of the company is "EASYJET AIRLINE COMPANY LIMITED"  ...  https://tinyurl.com/y3372wbm The company name is *styled* easyJet.  When you register a company, you have to use all capitals.  How you present and trademark your name is up to you.

Comment: To address one potential point of resistance to the idea of keeping it uncapitalized: English has the (usually unspoken) general rule "words that *don't* begin a sentence are uncapitalized"; but we are used to lots of specific exceptions (proper names, for example) that override that general rule. English has the general rule "words that *do* begin a sentence are capitalized"; but it makes perfect sense that there can be lots of specific exceptions (such as "easyJet") that override that general rule.

Comment: @JamesK That is irrelevant. What matters is **brand name and brand name recognitions**. All caps, indeed.The brand name is not all caps.

Answer (score 6):

If you're constrained to follow any *specific* style guide, it ***may*** have a definite position on whether to capitalise proper nouns like ***easyJet, eBay*** if they occur as the first "word" in a sentence. Probably not, though.

But this is from **Cambridge University Press** in [*Interchange*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n-9m1tqfo8kC&pg=PA21&dq=%22ebay%20is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGtK_V2NTrAhUisaQKHQsLCd04ChDoATADegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q=%22ebay%20is%22&f=false) (a series for adult and young-adult learners of English)...

[image]

The above is presented as a "promotional piece" for eBay, so arguably CUP are simply reproducing it without necessarily *endorsing* it. But it's followed by *student's question text* that repeats that "non-capitalisation" choice...

[image]

---

My guess is most writers would rather sidestep the issue completely - by rephrasing so the problematic term ***doesn't*** start a new sentence. It doesn't make any difference how many people agree or disagree with whatever capitalisation choice you make - there is no "perfect" way to deal with "orthographic anomalies" like this.

---

EDIT: I personally have no preference one way or the other - even with the potentially more challenging choice between ***eBay, Ebay,*** and ***EBay***. But since I've cited Cambridge University Press on the "Trade names trump standard grammar" side (backed by [CMOS](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Brand%20names%20or%20names%20of%20companies%20that%20are%20spelled%20with%20a%20lowercase%20initial%20letter%22)), I'll just say that both [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/en/articles/art20130716140724183) and [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/15/technology/ebay-cyberstalking-with-cockroaches-and-bloody-pig-face.html) use ***EBay*** to start a sentence, as noted in comments.

In short, it's [six of one and half-a-dozen of the other](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/six-of-one-and-half-a-dozen-of-the-other) (but you should at least be consistent).

> Blockquote

Comment: Sorry, I do not exactly understand your sentence *"If you're constrained to follow any specific style guide, that may have a definite position on whether to capitalise proper nouns like easyJet, eBay if they occur as the first "word" in a sentence."*. **"(...) that (...)"** refers to the style guide? (I am not a native speaker, I would have used "it" instead of "that" in that case). In other words, do you mean that only a specific style guide will (or rather - may) have a position on this topic, but there is no general rule?

Comment: sorry about that that :) I'll edit to make it easier to parse. I'm sure there won't be anything remotely close to a "general rule" for this. Things are even worse with ***eBay*** than they are with easyJet - if you check out (case-sensitive) hits on Google NGrams, you'll find ***EBay is** [blah blah]* occurs as well as ***Ebay is...*** and ***eBay is...*** But I find it hard to imagine any style guide would explicitly concern themselves with what to do about the ***second*** letter in ***eBay*** if for whatever reason they decided to capitalise the first letter.

Comment: No style guide would change a brand name...

Comment: @Lambie yet style guides do, including that of the BBC: https://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/en/articles/art20130716140724183

Comment: @phoog The company uses both EasyJet and easyJet. So the BBC didn't change anything at all. They just chose not to use the brand name.

Comment: @Lambie you didn't read the entry on eBay, did you?

Comment: Yes, and the New York Times uses eBay in any case. So that is the BBC being ornery.

Comment: It gets worse when the title case rule comes up.

Comment: @Lambie whether the BBC is ornery, whether they agree with the NY Times, and whether you agree with the BBC (and the many other organizations whose style guides do agree with theirs) are not relevant to the fact that your statement "no style guide would change a brand name" is false.

Comment: @Lambie Besides, the New York Times in fact uses *EBay* at the beginning of a sentence.  See https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/15/technology/ebay-cyberstalking-with-cockroaches-and-bloody-pig-face.html for a recent example.

Comment: @phoog No style guide would change a brand name: The brand name for the corporate name EasyJet = easyJet, The brand name for IBM = IBM, The brand name for AT&T is AT&T. **No style guide will use: EASYJET or Ibm or At&t or FaceBook,will they**? My goodness, is that so hard to agree with? Some companies corporate names and brand name LOGOS can differ. My statement is not false. You keep arguing with me because you have limited experience re corporate writing, I guess.

Comment: @Lambie I wonder whether you're using "brand name" to refer to "trademark" or, to be more precise, "word mark."  My only point is that several style guides exist that do call for capitalizing a word mark beginning with a lower case letter when that word mark appears at the beginning of a sentence.  Whether or not you want to call that "changing a brand name" makes little difference, but your answer suggests that you do, in which case the comment to which I was responded was incorrect. "Corporate writing" is not the only source of style guidance. Journalists tend to adopt a different approach.

Comment: @phoog CMOS: Brand names or names of companies that are spelled with a lowercase initial letter followed by a capital letter (eBay, iPod, iPhone, etc.) need not be capitalized at the beginning of a sentence or heading, **though some editors may prefer to reword**.” But NO style guide will do this: EASYJET, or Ibm or At&t or FaceBook.

Comment: @Lambie nobody's talking about FaceBook or the like.  We're talking about capitalization at the beginning of a sentence when the first word is a trademark that behind with a lower case letter.  Many style guides call for capitalization in that case.  You seemed to be asserting the contrary.

Comment: @phoog No one said anything about trademarks. This is about **company names**. I said no one changes a company name. Whatever the company uses, is what should be used in journalism or press releases, etc.. This is not a patent, this is not a trademark dispute. You are mistaken,.

Answer (score 0):

**Brand names cannot be changed when cited or referred to in writing.** However the brand name is written or spelled, it must stay that way even if it means starting a sentence with a lower-case letter.

So, easyJet is the brand name and EasyJet, **both used by the company**  and eBay. So, either one, I'd say.

[easyJet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyJet)

For example:

easyJet is an interesting company.
eBay is a corporate behemoth.

But editors will often reword a sentence to avoid this, as explained below.

Quote from ragan's PR Daily:

> **"eBay has a fabulous collection of vintage tube tops. iTunes must now compete with Amazon’s Prime Music**.
>
> **The Chicago Manual of Style has this to say: “Brand names or names of
> companies that are spelled with a lowercase initial letter followed by
> a capital letter (eBay, iPod, iPhone, etc.) need not be capitalized at
> the beginning of a sentence or heading, though some editors may prefer
> to reword.” That wasn’t always its rule, though**:
>
> **This departure from Chicago’s former usage recognizes not only the
> preferred usage of the owners of most such names but also the fact
> that such spellings are already capitalized (if only on the second
> letter). Company or product names with additional, internal capitals
> (sometimes called “midcaps”) should likewise be left unchanged
> (GlaxoSmithKline, HarperCollins, LexisNexis):"**.

Summary: Brand names are legal names and cannot be changed in writing.

https://www.prdaily.com/is-there-a-definitive-answer-to-this-capitalization-conundrum/

[Brand names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand#Types_of_brand_names)

**The Economist
The Bestselling Guide to English Usage**

> company names **Call companies by the names they call themselves. Here
> is a selection of names that are sometimes spelt incorrectly.**

abn amro
ACNeilsen
Allied Domecq
aol
AstraZeneca
AT&T (American Telephone) [see the full list in the PDF]

Refer to the full guide here:
[The Economist Style Guide](https://bordeure.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/the-economist-style-guide.pdf)

Comment: The first *and* last sentences of your answer say *brand names **cannot** be changed*, but the "authority" you cite for this from CMOS says they ***need not** be capitalized at the beginning of a sentence*. There's a world of difference between ***can't*** and ***needn't***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica This departure from Chicago’s former usage recognizes **not only the preferred usage of the owners of most such names but also the fact that such spellings are already capitalized (if only on the second letter)**. The point is that brand names stay the same.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the basic idea here - I just think you're overstating it. CMOS specifically "hedges" with ***may not*** and ***preferred usage***, but you're taking things significantly further. Particularly with the suggestion that because they're ***legal names***, there are actually legal implications here. Which I lump in with the ludicrous idea that the company that owns the trademarked ***Hoover*** brand name have some kind of legal right to pronounce on whether I'm even ***allowed*** to use that word as a verb, let alone whether I "must" capitalise it.

Comment: Yes, I am. Just look at magazines and newspapers. They ALWAYS use the brand's official spelling. And in some odd cases, there could be legal implication. But the social one would be more embarrassing....like when a junior press release writer writes the name incorrectly and sends out the release...Tell The Economist they are overstating it.

Comment: I just did a site-specific search of  www.bbc.co.uk/news for **ebay**. Two of the first three results are "incorrectly" capitalised, as ***EBay** said it did not tolerate such behaviour*  and ***EBay** is to drop PayPal as its main payments processor*. You can rail against such usages all you like, but you'll never get 100% compliance with any such "rules".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It isn't a rule. It's common stylisitc sense. And Jane Wakefield, a BBC technology reporter uses/used eBay: https://bordeure.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/the-economist-style-guide.pdf  In any event, The Economist is more high flying than the good ol' BBC.

Comment: It's not easy to do a case-sensitive search on bbc.com, and I've no idea how to track down their "house style guide" (which I'm sure will exist). But I've just repeated my site-specific search with ***easyjet has***, and every one of the first few pages of results where I can easily see that it starts a sentence has the first letter capitalised. This strongly suggests to me that the BBC has in fact come down on the opposite side of the fence to CMOS (and *you!* :) I have no preference or opinion; I'm simply reporting what usages occur.

Comment: The BBC is not The Economist. Many articles are whipped off very fast. Someone here is obviously tracking you. Your answer did not even address the brand name issue...easyjet has?? The  BBC uses EasyJet, capital E and capital J: https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-52722626 at bbc.com.uk

Comment: Note that for AT&T the economist does use lowercase small capitals. I'd argue that, if these aren't available, one should use uppercase/normal capitals. This question brings up an interesting point as not always did uppercase/lowercase bear the meanings they do today and were merely stylistic variations: Would we now consider small caps a different capitalisation or a different style/variation?

Comment: @ljrk Sorry, the cut and paste made it lower case, but in the PDF it is actually upper case. I have corrected it. AT&T is always upper case.

Comment: What about words that aren't brand names? For example, Unix commands are case-sensitive so it's technically (if not linguistically) correct to write the sentence "rm is the Unix command to remove a file."

Comment: @Lambie The thing is, semantically it is indeed lowercase, uppercase small caps look differently :)

Comment: @Simon Brady: Actually, I think that's the "killer argument" for the proposition *Is it **ever** legitimate to start an English sentence with a lower-case letter?* So far as I'm concerned, any of ***eBay, Ebay, EBay*** could be justified, and it wouldn't really make any difference which one you chose. But I wouldn't mind betting at least ***some*** people are running Unix/Linux systems with two commands that differ only by the case of the first letter of the relevant program name to be invoked. It could be truly disastrous to wrongly capitalise in documentation for a mission-critical system.

Comment: @SimonBrady This is not about Unix commands. It is specifically about company names.How about you and FF go to the chat room?